# Next.js crashes on invalid URL

Tags: next.js, invalid-url

Next.js server crashes (ERR_INVALID_URL) on requests with invalid url, like `*`.
Is there a way to prevent this? For instance, intercepting the error and wrapping it into the `try` block.
Solutions like the custom error page (`pages/_error.ts`) seems to not work.

Comment: Pleas provide your code .

Comment: I don't think there is a code I can provide. The crash reproduce on a blank next.js project with a simple http request like `request({ hostname : "localhost", port : 3000, path : "*" })`.

Comment: do you perhaps have an update?

Comment: Yes. This was a bug in next.js and a potential vulnerability.
I have created an issue on github and this was fixed on the next release.